# Solr Backup Not Working When Specifying a Location

Tags: solr

When we take a Solr backup, without a location specified - it works, and a backup snapshot folder is created in the data directory.

However, when specifying a folder, such as: http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/replication?command=backup&location=/backup_directory it always fails.

Looking at the Solr logs, I see this error:

SnapShooter
Failed to delete file:///backup_directory/snapshot.20200404134436807 after snapshot creation failed due to: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /backup_directory/snapshot.20200404134436807

SnapShooter
Exception while creating snapshot

I've searched for hours for a solution.  It looks like others have had this issue before too with various Solr versions.

Comment: Do the user Solr runs under have write access to the location given? Do the file system used support hard links? The part [about that code path in SnapShooter](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/SnapShooter.java#L245) is that it effectively leaves handling the error to any layers above without explicitly logging the problem. Do you get any log messages _before_ or _after_ the error you included? It would help narrow where in the code path it fails.

Comment: @MatsLindh it was a permission issue!  We were running the backup query as root, but Solr didn't have permissions to the backup folder. Thanks for all your help!  Can we mark this comment as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these errors are caused by Solr not having write access to the directory where the backup is supposed to go. This happens because Solr in most cases runs as a different user than the one that owns the backup directory (which might be root).

You can compare the user that Solr runs under - usually shown if you issue `ps aux | grep solr` or similar under Linux, and the who owns the directory - by using `ls -al` in the parent directory. Use `chown` to change ownership of the directory to the Solr user (unless it's being shared with other processes - in that case it'll depend on what you want to achieve).

Answer (score -1):

This error might be caused you didn't use trailing slash while setting the backup location. So you need to use the command:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/replication?command=backup&location=/backup_directory/
```